# angularjs ui-router dynamic ng-view in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm quite new to angularjs

I have problem with dynamic generate ui-view names in ng-repeat

http://plnkr.co/edit/vQjqYCB6mR34MS3coc1H?p=preview

Is it possible to generate ui-view names in ng-repeat and then how to configurate routes
to open `details.item.html` to `ui-view="item{{itemId}}"` ?